# Short story with a shrinking dress

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

I am looking to identify a sci-fi short story about a male scientist married to a very beautiful, but vain and sexually extreme woman. She had sexual relationships with lots of men at the same time - with her husbands full knowledge, but not approval.

In the end he invents a beautiful dress, which he gives her as a present. When she puts it on she can't take it off and it starts shrinking.

In the morning there's just a very hard sphere left on the floor, with crushed bones and flesh. A horrible way to die, but a perfect revenge. She was later proclaimed missing, but the husband was never suspected of any crime.

Comment: Unless it was a burqa, I'd expect almost a whole body's worth of squeezed-out meatpaste and more or less intact, if severed, head and limbs, in a room with a hard marble in the middle and bloodstains on walls and ceiling, smelling like an abattoir. These scientists really don't do practical :-)

Comment: Wow that's really awful and creepy and murderous, not a "perfect revenge."

Comment: @MissMonicaE As I remembered it she was really mean to her husband and she despised him.

Comment: Of course we're dealing with fiction and a simpler and less gruesome solution wouldn't have been as conducive to a good story, but still I think there's something to be said for divorce...

Comment: "Consider that a divorce."

Comment: @Michael That's still no call for murder.

Comment: Good thing it was just a story and not real life then...

Comment: MissMonicaE Don't complain to me, complain to the author for writing such a horrible STORY :)  Have you ever read the Babble? That's some gruesome stories in there.

Comment: @Michael I think their issue is your description of it as being "perfect revenge". Unless you're quoting the book, those are your words, not the author's.

Comment: Mwr247 I used it in a way that the character in the book describes his situation and why he was doing it. He wanted revenge. Perfect in the sense it was not a random murder but a planned action since he had to invent the murder weapon first and then set it up and murder her followed by the absence of her body no where to be found and no suspicions from anybody of murder charges or whatever because everybody knew about her dubious life style and they all thought she had run away with one of her lovers or something. I don't even understand why people get upset about it? It's a story, fiction.